# Use ngFor to make Angular Material Table Short

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngfor

I am using Angular Material Table for data table purpose.

But, I want to know how can I use Angular For Loop in order to write less code to shorten the tables' td/tr code in html file.

**Angular Material Table HTML file:**

```
<div>
  <mat-table [dataSource]="tableData" matSort>
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="index">
      <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>#</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
        {{ paginatorRef.pageIndex * paginatorRef.pageSize + (i + 1) }}
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ip">
      <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
        IP Address
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.ip }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="host">
      <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
        Host
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.browser }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="datetime">
      <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
        Date & Time
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{ element.datetime | date: "dd MMM yyyy, hh:mm:ss a" }}
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
  <mat-paginator #paginatorRef [showFirstLastButtons]></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Angular Material Table TS file(short):

```
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  tableData: any;
  columns: string[] = ['index', 'ip', 'host', 'datetime'];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is the shortest/only way you can do to display an Angular Material table.
The purpose of Angular Material is to save you some extra work when it comes to filter, sort and pagination. So just use it like explained in their docs.

Comment: Yes I agree. But what If I want to use the same table with different dataSource and different columns everywhere inside the application? Do you have any suggestion or code snippet for the same? Please share if any.